# Grid column as combobox type displays a list of objects as [object Object]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, extjs

I have the following problem:

I am trying to create a grid in which one of the columns we have Countries in which our users operate. Thus I want to be able to edit the countries(176 in my database) with a combobox.

Unfortuantely, the current countries which are selected so far display as [object Object].

In my C# code the model of the users has a property named CountriesDetails which is a list of objects named Country. The object Country has id(i.e. 1) and name(i.e United States).

Here is my js code for this grid:

```
var mstore3 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { remoteSort: true, pageSize: 20, listeners: { reload: function () { console.debug('reload'); } } });

        var store3 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'store3',
            autoLoad: true,
            remoteSort: true,
            pageSize: 1000,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                //enablePaging: true,
                url: 'GetProxyCMSWithCountries',
                reader: { type: 'json', rootProperty: 'data', totalProperty: 'total' },
                pageParam: 'page', limitParam: 'limit', startParam: 'start'
            },
            listeners: {
                load: function (self, records, successful) { mstore3.setProxy({ type: "memory", enablePaging: true, data: records }); mstore3.load(); }
            }
        });

var grid3 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'CMS List',
            id: 'CMSGrid',
            minHeight: 640,
            store: mstore3,
            realstore: store3,
            viewConfig: { enableTextSelection: true },
            bbar: { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', store: mstore3, displayInfo: true, inputItemWidth: 50, doRefresh: function () { store3.reload() } },

            //listeners: { select: function (grid, record) { App.selCMSRow = record.data; }, },

            columns: [
                { text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'Id', flex: 0.3 },
                { text: 'Short Name', dataIndex: 'ShortName', flex: 1, editor: true, filter: { type: 'string' } },
                { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 2, editor: true, filter: { type: 'string' } },[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb8X4.png)'string' } },
                {
                    text: 'Country', dataIndex: 'CountriesDetails', flex: 2,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combo', 
                        allowBlank: false,
                        displayField: 'CountriesDetails.Name',
                        valueField: 'Id'
                    }, 
                    filter: { type: 'list' } },
                { text: 'State', dataIndex: 'State', flex: 0.5, editor: true, filter: { type: 'string' } },
                { text: 'City', dataIndex: 'City', flex: 1, editor: true, filter: { type: 'string' } },
                { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'Phone', flex: 1, editor: true, filter: { type: 'string' } 
}]
```

The function which I am calling in my store 'GetProxyCMSWithCountries' gets all the records of users from the db.

Thank you in advance

[Grid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opb1F.png)

Comment: Just a hunch, but what happens if you change displayField: 'CountriesDetails.Name' to displayField: 'Name'?

Comment: @b166er already tried that. The output is the same

Comment: I took a bit more time reading your object structure, change displayField: 'CountriesDetails.Country.Name'

Comment: @b166er still the same. 
`public List<Country> CountriesDetails` 
this is how the property looks like in my model. I do not think 'Country' would be recognised in ext.js

Comment: You have to setup ExtJS models to interpret the incoming (presumably JSON) data and map the structure to ExtJS fields. After you set up the models for user, country etc., you can use the fields names in the grid and the combobox.

Comment: ExtJS does the favour for you if a model is not specified that maps the simply recognisable fields and creates a model internally. But this works only in simple cases, like a string field in the JSON will be mapped correctly.

Comment: But in more complicated cases you need to define the model yourself. Check the `mapping` property for example [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-mapping).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Turns out there is no out of the box combobox with multiselect answer. However, @Peter Koltai's answer is absolutely correct and could be used when trying to map data from model which has a list as a property to a grid column.